# Spring mvc web service gives Content-Type →text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 expected is [{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"}]

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, service

In Spring 4 MVC the expected content type is coming as text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 instead of application/json and gives Error

> 415: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 415

in postman. how could this be resolved.
How to set response header for getting application/json in Spring rest controller?

Comment: add controller method code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'Accept': 'application/json'` in header.

Comment: Neither works and doesnt print the SOP and gives the error  WAS console - SRTServletRes W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/dummyPut", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE ) //@PostMapping(value = "/dummy") public ResponseEntity<RequestTypeDummy> dummyPut(@RequestBody RequestTypeDummy reqObj) { System.out.println("inside dummy "); System.out.println("reqObj.regionID)"+reqObj.regionID); return new ResponseEntity<RequestTypeDummy>(reqObj, HttpStatus.OK); } seems not working and same error exist. i am using WAS 8.5.5.13

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/dummy1", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8") public String dummy1(@RequestBody RequestTypeDummy reqObj)  { System.out.println("inside dummy "); System.out.println("reqObj.regionID)"+reqObj.getRegionID()); return reqObj; }

Answer (score 0):

This how you specify the response type in Spring MVC :

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/uri", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and still gives same error. in addition it shows same error in WAS console - SRTServletRes W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the code of your Spring MVC controller?